# Installing a new NIC into my Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I currently have a physical machine, running Unbutu Server 22, and connected to my router via an RJ45 port that is on the motherboard. (let's call it "the old port")

I just bought a PCIe 10gbps NIC (TP-Link TX401), and I was hoping that I could just plug it in the computer, change the RJ45 cable from the old port to the new port, and that everything would work automagically...

How naive I was :-)

When I turn on the computer with the new card plugged in, network is completey non-functional (cannot run ping for example), even when I plug the RJ45 cable on the old port! Both interface (old and new) are marked as "DOWN". Note that when I bring the interface of the new card to "UP", the leds start blinking, so it seems that the card is recognized well (even though I want to point out that I did not install the drivers).

What I tried :

- Disable completely the old port from the BIOS.
- Bring the old interface UP (sudo ip link set enp3s0 up)
- Bring the new interface UP (sudo ip link set enp1s0 up)

In all cases, neither interface seem to have an IP address... (ip link show)

What is the proper procedure to set up this new network card ?

Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Network interfaces don’t just magically configure themselves. Even DHCP must be set up. You should investigate how the old NIC was set up: ifupdown, systemd-networkd, …

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration